# I can't install tensorflow 2.1.0 version

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I have a problem that i can't install tensorflow 2.1.0 version using pip

every time i try , i have this message:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

my machine specs:  windows 10 , 64 bit , python 3.7 pip 20.1

Answer (score 1):

Yep this is an issue with that version of python, try using python 3.6, it solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem resolved by upgrading the pip.

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`