# cannot install TensorFlow 2.2.0 on a server

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, server, putty

i am trying to install `TensorFlow 2.2.0` inside a server using putty but I cannot as it raises an error

```
 Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.2.0 (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0
```

python version is `2.7.17`
python3 version is `3.6.9`

any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Your server is most likely using Python 3.3 or 3.4, which were only supported (in stable releases) up to [2.0.0b1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.0.0b1) (click "Download files" to see the list of Wheel packages for each version). The next version, [2.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.0.0), supports only Python 3.5 to 3.7, and version [2.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0) supports Python 3.5 to 3.8.

Comment: There are several related questions, most likely one of them is a duplicate of your problem: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61623355/1782792), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59500220/1782792), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48390095/1782792) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38896424/1782792).

Comment: yes,. My system has 3.6.9  but the model that I serve inside the server is written with 3.7.7. How to specify this python versions inside a vev?

Comment: Upgrade `pip` to latest version and try once with `pip3 install tensorflow` instead of `pip install tensorflow`